# Access other website API

Tags: rest-api, api

How to access other website api from salesforce?
I wanna access the career builder api(http://developer.careerbuilder.com/endpoints/index#collapse4)

For that What I've to do?

Answer (score 1):

To do this you will be required to make an web service callout using Apex in your controller (for example, assuming you want the data displayed on a VF page). To call out to the application service for example (see docs here):

```
public void getApplication(String applicationId) {
  HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
  req.setMethod('GET');
  req.setEndpoint('https://api.careerbuilder.com/cbapi/application/' + applicationId);
  req.setHeader('DeveloperKey', 'Your career builder developer key');
  req.setHeader('HostSite', URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm());
  Http http = new Http();
  HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
  System.debug(res.getBody());
}
```

That is an example call and should be enough to get you moving. The documentation from CareerBuilder you linked to seems clear about parameters and URLs for use.